# Best way to force activity finish if user is logged out (Android)

Tags: android

I have this app where I have a user session. And then I have a set of activities that should only be entered by users with an active session. Any suggestion on how to deal with this scenario? I wanted to escape to the scenario of doing the same verification code in all activity onCreate.

For example, I would have to put this code in every OnCreate:

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    if(loggedOut) {
     finish();
     return;
    }
}
```

I wanted to know which is the best way to deal with this, due to Android lifecycles.

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you check *before* starting the Activity?

Comment: That is an option, but I would have to repeat the same code everywhere. I was trying to see if there was a good solution without code repetition.

Comment: Сreate one BaseActivity wherein make this check-logic and extend all your activities from her.

Comment: How do you log your user out? Is that token related or time related, or button?

Comment: well, but if I do the finish() on the superclass, that won't stop running the code on the "onCreate" of the subclass .. @АндройдАндройд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if User logged in onResume. if you check login status onCreate, when user go to another activity and return to same activity (or User phone rings) onResume will run Not onCreate.

```
    public void onResume(...) {
     RequiredLogin();
    }
```

and you can define RequiredLogin in another class and reuse it in all activities.

```
RequiredLogin(){
  if(loggedOut) {finish();return;}
}
```

Comment: This just has one problem. What if in my onResume() i have code that deals with the logged user. That coud eventually lead to some null pointer exceptions. 

For example:

public void onResume() {
  RequiredLogin();
  User user = getCurrentUser();
  user.getName();
}

If the user is logged out it would give me a null user.

Comment: huh? what NPE? check if `user` is not null before you use it... also it would be bette use singleton like `CurrentUser.getInstance(context)` and eventualy popup the login screen from there ..

Comment: you should check if user data is not null. for example check if userToken was set or it is null.

Comment: I totally get you! I was just looking for the perfect scenario @Selvin, where I could just avoid running user related code if I detected that it wasn't logged in (and with the less possible repetition and verifications).

Comment: when you checked it in onResum, when activity create for firs run and when activity resume (for example by pressing back button) it will check.